Error with Jenkins High Availability setup (Active Passive), using Gearman plugin
We have a Jenkins Active Passive setup and we have a requirement to keep the /var/lib/jenkins/nodes and /var/lib/jenkins/plugins directory on both server to be in sync as the /var/lib/jenkins directory is already on a shared file path.
I came across the Gearman plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/gearman-plugin/) and trying to configure the same, but the data is not getting synced
We have 2 Jenkins master server, Server-A and Server-B. We have installed Gearman plugin on both the servers.
On the Server-A in the system configure --> Gearman Plugin configure we have provided the Server-B ip address and port number in place of the Gearman Server Host and Gearman Server Port.
On Server-B we have provided the Server-A ip address and port number in place of the Gearman Server Host and Gearman Server Port .
The test connection shows successful but the sync is not working. Can anyone help how to configure the Gearman plugin for highavailability?
